# Copy text from UITextView into clipboard using UIPasteBoard in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm a beginner at developing for iOS, and after doing some research on the web, I still couldn't find a way that I can set a button to copy the entire text from a textview. I've seen some tutorials but most of them are old, and some of them are very confusing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: on button click action add `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = textView.text`

Comment: I tried this code, but once I run my app I click the copy button and the app crashes and redirects me to the AppDelegate screen, any ideas ? Sorry as I said, I'm a beginner.

Comment: any crash log in console?

Comment: It redirects me to this line `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`and it highlights it green and it says "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: in the debug area of Xcode, there is a console for logs. you can see crash logs there in this case. update with the error message in console.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks for the help, it really solved my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
@IBAction func copyButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = textToCopy.text
}
```